# Дерево в SQL

Tags: дерево, sql

Всем добрый день. У меня появился такой вопрос. Скажем имеется таблица в которой хранится древовидная структура. Допустим в таблице есть Id - ид записи и IdParent - ид родителя. Как можно с помощью sql запроса выбрать самого верхнего родителя у записи с id = 10? Возможно ли вообще такое средствами sql?

Comment: А какая субд?

Comment: желательно чтобы это не было зависимо от средств конкретной субд, только средства самого sql. Ну а если без этого никак то sql server

Comment: По факту надо определить, к какому корневому узлу (pid = 0) относится текущий элемент?

Comment: да правильно

Comment: Попробуйте Nested Sets, если количество запросов на добавление/удаление записей по сравнению с чтением значительно меньше (то есть из базы в основном будут читать, а не писать), то NS- отличное решение для хранения деревьев, а подобные задачи там решаются крайне просто.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможность создания рекурсивных запросов есть начиная с SQL 1999. Это возможно с помощью  оператора WITH. В MS Sql будет выглядеть так:

```
WITH rec AS
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Id = 10

   UNION ALL

   SELECT mt.*
   FROM MyTable mt
   JOIN rec p ON mt.parentID = p.id
)
SELECT ParentId 
FROM rec
where Id = 10
```

Если не ошибаюсь, в MySql это работать не будет. Насчет Oracle - не в курсе

Answer (score 3):

[[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus) - вместо NS, я бы посоветовал использовать `Materialized path` ([`PostgreSQL Ltree`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html)). У NS возникают большие нагрузки при перемещении узла с большим количеством дочерних элементов, так как для каждого элемента необходимо пересчитать левый и правый ключи.

Answer (score 2):

По стандарту вроде нельзя. Для Oracle, PostgresSQL есть реализация древовидных запросов. В MS sql server'e вроде от версии зависит, в новых вроде появилась возможность но не уверен. По стандарту можно только если костылями со вложенными запросами ограничив по уровню вложенности например так:

```
  select * from table as l0 
  left join table as l1 on(l1.parent_id = l0.id)
  left join table as l2 on(l2.parent_id = l2.id)
  left join table as l3 on(l3.parent_id = l1.id)
  where l0.parent_id is null and (l1.id = 10 or l2.id = 10 or l3.id = 10)
```